# For loop returning process after 2nd iteration

Tags: c++, csv, for-loop, fstream

I'm writing code to take a player's name as input, search a csv file for the name and if the file contains the name save the entire row to a vector within a vector to be accessed later. However the process is returned after the 2nd iteration of the for loop (it's supposed to loop 11 times). Any help is appreciated! Here's the code:

```
[#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "fantasy.h"

using namespace std;

player::player(void)
{
    NULL;
}

void player::playerinput(void)
{
    playername = " ";
    playern2 = " ";
    int count = 0;
    fileName = " ";
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
        std::cout << "Enter player second name: ";
        std::cin >> playername;
        player::opencsv(playername);
    }
}

void player::opencsv(string playername){
    count = 0;
    run = true;
    string line, word, temp;
    vector<string> row = {};
    fin.open("C:/Users/Desktop/CSProject/cleaned_players 1819.csv", ios::in);
    while(run){
        row.clear();
        getline(fin, line);
        stringstream s(line);
        while (getline(s, word, ',')){
            row.push_back(word);
        }
        playern2 = row\[1\];
        if(playern2 == playername){
            count = 1;
            players.push_back(row);
            std::cout << "Player: " << row\[0\] << " " << row\[1\] << " added to database" << std::endl;
            run = false;
            return;
        }
        if(count = 0){
            std::cout << "Player not in database" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    row.clear();
    fin.clear();
}

int main()
{
    player P1;
    P1.playerinput();
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXolK.png)

Comment: Instead of re-reading the file on each line of input, why not read it once, then test for presence? `std::map` is great for this case.

Comment: If you want to clear out your strings, setting them to be equal to a single space is not the right idea. Do `""` if you must. Even better: Make those variables local to the input function itself, don't have them as properties in the class. You already pass it in as an argument to the other function anyway. Tip: Pass strings as `const std::string&` whenever possible, it avoids copying.

Comment: Having a function body of `NULL` is completely pointless and it's also kind of concerning since it's not clear why you'd do that in the first place. Did you pick that up from a tutorial somewhere? Likewise, you can leave empty argument lists empty, there's no need for `(void)`.

Comment: You'll also want to keep in mind the [CSV format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) is more complicated than "split on commas". There's quoting issues as well for things with commas in them, like `"Bob Jones, Jr."`.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the numerous suggestions. I'm going to try implement them now and see if it fixes my problem. also the null function body was me trying to fix a previous error and I forgot to remove it lol